# TypeError: string indices must be integers however it is an integer

Tags: python

I am trying to develop an xy cut algorithm with python 3.5 it was all great until i had an error that says

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

in

```
I1=img[:,1:cutPoint-1:1,:]
```

it appears that `cutPoint` is read as a string but i made sure to convert it into an integer and used `print` to verify it type and it's an integer i don't really get what the problem is and how to fix it.

Here is a part of my code:

```
if maxValLine<10 and maxValCol<10:
        result=img
    else:
        #determiner coupe selon x ou y
        if maxValLine>maxValCol:
            cutpoint=(locsLine[indexLine]+locsLine[indexLine+1])/2 
            cutPoint=math.floor(cutPoint)
            print(cutpoint) #it shows the value 303
            print(type(cutPoint)) #gives <class 'int'>
            I1=img[1:cutPoint-1:1,:,:] !!!the issue is here 
            I2=img[cutPoint:end:1,:,:]
            cv2.imshow('I1',I1)
            cv2.imshow('I2',I2)
            result=[recusiveCut(I1),recusiveCut(I2)]
            return result
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you define `img`?

Comment: use `//2` instead of `/2` and avoid `floor`

Comment: I tried to use // also but the same error accures, i created a function where i read the image normally and convert it into grayscale my function starts like this: def recusiveCut(img):
    #Binairization
    im = cv2.imread(img)
    #I=Image.copy()
    im_gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im_gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    #cv2.imshow('bw',thresh)

Comment: `[1:cutPoint-1:1,:,:]` This does not look like a valid index or slice at all (and same goes for the next line). Even if you replaced `cutPoint` with literal `int`, it would not change that.

Comment: @OndrejK. it's the syntax i found to slice the image how can I fix this?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings): "If the slice list contains at least one comma, the key is a tuple containing the conversion of the slice items". So this would basically result in trying to use a tuple of three slices as a key/index (not an int). But really the question is, what exactly is it that you are trying to say/get?

Comment: I am trying to slice the original image depending on the cutPoint into two images I1 and I2 the first one must take the same part of the original image and stops when it arrives to the cutpoint and the rest lust be I2, it's a way of segmentaing a scanned page i have but i really don't get how to fix the slicing part because i always find the same syntax used as i did like in here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html and other websites

Comment: @amina: Yes, that could have worked on a multi-dimensional numpy array. But as the other bit of the error message suggested, it's not OK for a string which expects a `int` index (and not a tuple (of slices)). `img` is probably not what you expect it to be at that point?

Comment: I will look more into it but i am pretty sure that i am working with a multi-dimensional array(I have verified it ),thank you @OndrejK.

Comment: You could show us a bit more code clarifying how `img` came to be. You can also run your script in a debugger (instead of running `python script.py` use `python -m pdb script.py`) and inspect `img` at the point the script has failed.

Comment: I have created a function called "recusiveCut" with parameter img (name of the image) and it starts like this #Binarization
    im = cv2.imread(img)
    #I=Image.copy()
    im_gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(im_gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    #cv2.imshow('bw',thresh)

Comment: The image is a 3D image numpy array, between this piece of code and the previous one there are some calculations to find maxvalLine and maxvalCol so it doesn't affect the shape of the original image or any of that(sorry that i can't post it) in the main function here is how i called the function im ="doc4.jpg"
recusiveCut(im)
 
to guarantee you the type of my the image I have used print (type(im)) and print(im) to see the array here are the results <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[[ 97 111 130]
  [133 149 162]
  [  9  24  33]
 ...
  [122 121 130]
  ]]  your help is so much appreciated.